# @PersistenceContext entitymanager working without transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm calling the following method in service from controller where no @Transnational at the top of method :

```
@Override
public void test1(Pageable pageable) {
    {
        Query query =entityManager.createQuery("SELECT U from User U",User.class);
        List<User> users=query.getResultList();
        User user=new User();
        user.setName("hello");
        user.setLastName("hello");
         entityManager.persist(user);
    }
}
```

I was confused that it worked and the result is committed at the end of method , the entitymanager injected in the service with :

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

can anybody explains how the transaction is created on method without transnational ?

---

update:
my bad I was using @Transactional on interface without noticing it. but how does the select query work ? when is the session created ?
spring.jpa.open-in-view is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it's possible when using Open Session In View / Open Entity Manager In View patterns.

Spring has Open Entity Manager In View pattern enabled by default (i.e property `spring.jpa.open-in-view` is set to `true`).

This property tells Spring to register `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` which does the trick.

**UPD.**

JPA doesn't enforce transactions on read operations. That's why select statement works event without `@Transactional`.

If the user doesn't declare transaction boundaries, then each select statement will be executed in a separate transaction (autocommit mode) - that's how JDBC handles this case (i.e JDBC opens a transaction).

JDBC closes transaction immediately after the statement execution and doesn't bind this transaction to any thread.

Comment: No i disabled it :)

Comment: updated I was missing transaction on interface but the select query is working even without transactional , when is the session created for it ?

Comment: If the user doesn't declare transaction boundaries, then each statement will be executed in a separate transaction (autocommit mode) , then why the persist didn't work if the statement runs inside transaction ? eg. :No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread

Comment: Because JDBC closes transaction immediately after "select" statement has been executed. So transaction is opened only for "select" and no one bind this transaction to current thread

Comment: so you mean the transaction will be opened for read only not for write ? can you please update the answer ?

Comment: Yes, transaction is opened only for "read" operation and JDBC closes this transaction immediately after receiving the result